# C#/WPF - Why does this separate thread on separate form hang the entire application?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

**The Problem**

I'm writing software which detects which active screens are open and sends pings to the main application for suggestions. The problem is, no matter everything I've tried, whenever I activate the infinite loop in a separate form OR thread, it hangs the entire application, and all forms involved.

**What I have tried**
Yes the classes are in the same namespace.
Yes I have tried background workers.
Yes I do realize my dispatcher is activating a new instance of a separate thread with invocation capabilities.

---

**The Code**

---

Main Window

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //..deleteted irrelevent code..//

        //Activate Application Detection
        AppDetect_Infinite AI = new AppDetect_Infinite();
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => AI.run()));
        thread.Start();
    }
```

AppDetect_Infinite Window

```
public partial class AppDetect_Infinite : Window
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetActiveWindow();
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);
    public AppDetect_Infinite()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void run() {
            string newWindows = "";
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
        while (true)
        {
        const int nChars = 256;
        StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder(nChars);
        IntPtr handle = GetForegroundWindow();
        if ((GetWindowText(handle, Buff, nChars) > 0) && (newWindows.Contains(Buff.ToString()) == false))
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(Buff.ToString());
            if (newWindows.Length == 0)
                newWindows = Buff.ToString();
            else
                newWindows = newWindows + "|" + Buff.ToString();

            Process[] AllProcess = Process.GetProcesses();
            String title = Buff.ToString();

            foreach (Process pro in AllProcess)
            {
                if (title.Equals(pro.MainWindowTitle))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string[] fn = pro.MainModule.FileName.ToString().Split('\\');
                        //MessageBox.Show(Buff.ToString() + " | " + fn[fn.Length - 1]);
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
            }
                }
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

Any ideas how I can activate this separate thread without having it give me the spinning blue halo of death over my main application? I'm open to all suggestions.

Comment: Try using a BackgroundWorker instead of a Thread.

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Yes, tried debugging and background workers. thanks.

Comment: You are mixing WPF and WinForms. I don't think you want or need that. Take a look at this blog post for creating WPF windows in separate threads: http://eprystupa.wordpress.com/2008/07/28/running-wpf-application-with-multiple-ui-threads/

Comment: Thank you Paul, i read this and migrated my code back to the MainForm and it worked from their.

Comment: Ok, why the downvote? I believe this is an acceptable question. Would the downvoter please leave a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're scheduling something onto dispatcher via `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` in the new thread, but do not run dispatcher itself on this thread.
In other words, you need to run message loop in this new thread somehow. One way is to run `this.ShowDialog()` in your `AppDetect_Infinite`.
Another would be just `Application.Run`

**EDIT:** `ShowDialog` won't work. Your `AppDetect_Infinite` binds to main thread in the constructor. If you want it to run in another thread - you should create it there in the first place.

And creating threads upon threads upon threads is not necessary. At least I don't know why to create another thread in the lambda in `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`

**EDIT2:** ...and mixing WPF and WinForms without good reason does not seem like a good idea either.

Comment: disabling dispatcher.begininvoke worked. I can detect apps in parallel with my application running. But I cannot update elements in the main form. How can I call a public method in the main form without re-initializing it?

Comment: after seeing you and Paul Sasik suggest that mixing these two forms were a bad idea, i migrated the scanning code back to the mainform and triggered a dispatcher.invoke after the scan detected a difference. Now it is functioning and running quickly without main form interruption. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are not executing your code in another thread because Dispatcher is associated to main thread, from MSDN:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke

Executes a delegate asynchronously on the thread the Dispatcher is associated with.
```

If you want not to block main thread execute your code through a Thread or the ThreadPool, do not call dispatcher or it will be executed on main thread.

Comment: Well, he *is* creating another thread, it's just that that other thread isn't doing anything except scheduling work to be done on the UI thread.

Comment: Yes, ok, maybe my answer was not total y clear, let me modify it

Comment: It was ignorant of me to activate nested threads and invoke the main form while still trying to keep it running successfully. Disabling the dispatcher.begininvoke did function. But the bigger question is, without this dispatcher active, how can i update the main form elements once data has been detected.

Comment: Just call the dispatcher when you need it, in your case surround the part inside the "if ((GetWindowText(handle, Buff, nChars) > 0)..." block with a Dispatcher.Invoke (not BeginInvoke, to make it synchronous and avoid having thousands of messageboxes pop out ;) )

Comment: Also, as a recomendation, add a Thread.Sleep(1) at the beginning of your while, it will eat a magnitude less of CPU resources and will still be enough responsive.

Comment: Thank you very much Gusman, migrating my code back into the main form and hosting it locally patched the issue.